# Does Apache Tuscany SCA come in a 64 bit version?

Tags: sca, apache-tuscany

Is there a 64 bit version of Apache Tuscany SCA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tuscany/sca-cpp/trunk/INSTALL

Tuscany provides two automated install scripts for Ubuntu. You can start with
a fresh Ubuntu Server 10.10 64-bit system and these scripts will take care of
all the download, build and installation steps for you.